# Preventing the IDE from changing a package's "requires" clause

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I have a shared runtime package that I am using to support an application that uses packages as a plugin system. I have included several third party units in the shared package to reduce the number of BPLs that have to be distributed.

Delphi seems to have some headaches with this set up, occasionally updating only the DCP file in the "shared DCP" area (C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Dcp on my machine) and not the one in the DCP output directory (as specified in the project options).

That isn't my main problem though... My main problem is that Delphi throws up this dialog quite often:

[image: Delphi Change Package Dialog]

(this is just an example, it happens for other packages I have installed as well)

Now, in Delphi 2009, at least when I cancel this dialog (and click yes on the dialog that comes up next), it doesn't change anything. Previous versions would still proceed to munge my dpk file.

I currently can't get the damned dialog to stop coming up. The package is set as a runtime package, it does not have any packages "required" (other than the VCL ones). I thought I had it licked a month ago, but it has started coming up again.

There are no changes to the DPK file or the DPROJ file.

I know why it is doing it... Delphi is trying to keep this package internally consistent with other packages in the IDE, just in case I install it. I would like to stop the IDE doing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

N@

Comment: Sorry for the delay in checking on answers, I have been in a theatre wielding lights for the last couple of days!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should explicitly reference each of the units mentioned in the dialog in the **contains** section of the DPK file. The dialog only shows units that are **implicitly** (= not listed in **contains**) included and suggests **requiring** the package they originally belong to.

Comment: +1. Also, look for the pointers to help avoid this in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215664/is-implicitly-imported-always-a-bad-thing-in-delphi-packages/1216131#1216131

Comment: Thank you Uwe! So basically, if a package is installed that contains one of the units that isn't *explicitly* required, it will require the package... instead of giving you a list of units that it has implicitly linked in (as is that case normally).

Comment: I think the units are also linked in implicitly in the first place, but it is suggested to require those packages. If you click OK it is actually done.

Answer (score 2):

If delphi is requiring this package is because you are using some units that are not in the package itself or in the required packages.

By the way, if Delphi is prompting you for use this package is because Delphi "knows" a package with these units you need and you are not declaring, also the package will be compiled with these units "implicity" imported. This could produce an inconsistent application if you are working with packages. Remember a Unit only can be loaded one time in an application.